# Problemas com NOLOCK, READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sempre vejo sqls montadas com WITH NOLOCK que dizem melhorar a performance, porém já ouvi também que NOLOCK está obsoleto e o que deve ser usado agora é o READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT, nesse cenário minhas dúvidas são:

1 - NOLOCK melhora mesmo a performance ou é mito, tenho como mensurar isso através de uma consulta com SET STATISTICS TIME ON por exemplo;

2 - como uso o READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT? algum exemplo prático que pode ser mensurado também?

3 - Qual são os correspondentes em MySQL e ORACLE;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As versões do Microsoft SQL Server anteriores à 2005 não possuiam o recurso de **SNAPSHOT**, então o hint **WITH NOLOCK** podia de fato melhorar a performance por fazer com que uma consulta (um SELECT) não ficasse esperando a liberação de registros bloqueados por uma transação longa.

Então uma breve explanação sobre cada um dos termos citados na sua pergunta:

#### READ COMMITTED

Um SELECT executado em uma sessão configurada como READ COMMITTED trará apenas registros já commitados. Então se este SELECT encontrar um registro alterado por outra transação, ele ficará esperando o registro ser liberado por um COMMIT ou um ROLBACK.

#### WITH NOLOCK

Um SELECT usando este hint trará também registros alterados por outra transação pendente (uma transação que ainda não foi concluída com COMMIT ou ROLBACK). Assim, este SELECT pode trazer registros "sujos", uma vez que você pode ler um valor alterado por aquela transação mas que depois venha a ser restaurado ao seu valor original no caso de um ROLBACK.

#### SNAPSHOT

É um recurso comum dos servidores de banco de dados que só foi introduzido no MS SQL Server na sua versão 2005.

Com este recurso ativo, o SGBD mantém uma fotografia do estado original do registro quando ele é alterado por uma transação. Assim um SELECT em outra transação pode ler a última versão commitada do registro sem precisar esperar pela conclusão da outra transação pendente e sem ler um registro "sujo".

#### READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT

Um SELECT executado em uma seção configurada com READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT lerá apenas registros já commitados, mas graças ao recurso SNAPSHOT este SELECT não ficará bloqueado quando o registro tiver sido alterado por outra transação pendente; ao invés, o SELECT vai ler a última versão commitada do registro.

## Suas perguntas:

#### 1 - NOLOCK melhora mesmo a performance ou é mito, tenho como mensurar isso através de uma consulta com SET STATISTICS TIME ON por exemplo?

Pode melhorar sim porque seus SELECTs nunca vão ficar bloqueados. Melhora a performance significativamente em sistemas <sub>(ruins)</sub> que utilizam muitas transações longas. Isso é bem difícil de mensurar pois um SELECT bloqueado vai demorar mais ou menos dependendo do uso simultâneo do sistema por outros usuários.

#### 2 - como uso o READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT? algum exemplo prático que pode ser mensurado também?

Você deve ativar este recurso **SNAPSHOT** no banco de dados (na versão 2005 vinha desativado por padrão - não sei se isso mudou nas versões seguintes) e deve configurar suas sessões para utilizarem este nível de isolamento de transação (*read commited snapshot*). Com isso você pode deixar de usar o hint WITH NOLOCK sem sofrer com SELECTs bloqueados. **É provavelmente a coisa certa a se fazer.** Infelizmente isso também é difícil de mensurar pelo mesmo motivo já citado: o ganho em performance depende do uso simultâneo do sistema por outros usuários.

#### 3 - Qual são os correspondentes em MySQL e ORACLE?

Desconheço um equivalente ao hint WITH NOLOCK nestes SGBDs, mas o fato é que eles possuem o recurso **SNAPSHOT** e ele vem ativado por padrão.

<sub>Tentei ser sucinto em um assunto um tanto complexo. Se algo não ficou claro deixe um comentário que vou melhorando a resposta.</sub>